# append and prepend text to a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to be able to search for a certain word in a string, and append and prepend characters to every instance of that word.

example:

```
I like cats, cats are awesome! I wish I had cats!
```

becomes:

```
I like (cats), (cats) are awesome! I wish I had (cats)!
```

I know I could use

```
str_replace( 'cats', '(cats)', $string );
```

but I would have to write "cats" twice.
I want a method that only requires me to write it once.

Comment: You mean you'd like a function call like `str_wrap(needle,prefix,suffix,haystack)` ? (BTW, while there may be a function out there called `str_wrap`, I'm not saying this is the format of the call to it, nor the intent of the function). Can you tell us why you have an aversion to putting "cats" twice?

Comment: Put it inside a variable? You will have to write the variable name twice, but it's not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a `preg_replace()` with back references: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
preg_replace("/cats/smi","($0)",$string);
```

Comment: @williammalo, can you tell us why you didn't want to write "cats" twice? Just curious.

Comment: @williammalo, be aware that using a regex rather than a simple `str_replace()` is quite a bit more expensive on cpu.

Comment: @JonathanM  I have a huge plain text list of values I need to parenthesize, and I wanted to make it easier to write the code.

Comment: @williammalo, the number of replacements you're going to be doing could get quite cpu-expensive with regex. I posted a possible alternative in another answer here.

Comment: If you understood what pattern flags `s` and `m` did you wouldn't be using them.  Unfortunately, researchers will be copy pasting your code. Either of the other answers should be used instead.  Also, no-one asked about word boundaries which is a necessary distinction to clarify in this type of question.

Comment: @Andrew Age of a page is totally irrelevant to researchers.  Quality matters so that people don't use the wrong code in their project.  You have thousands of rep points, this means researchers can "trust" you to provide good stuff.  An accepted answer more-so needs to be "right".

Answer (score 8):

```
$search = 'cats';
preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/', '($0)', $string);
```

Paraphrased from the [`preg_replace` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> The replacement string may contain references of the form `$n`. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th parenthesized pattern. `$0` refers to the text matched by the whole pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You commented:

> I have a huge plain text list of values I need to parenthesize, and I
>   wanted to make it easier to write the code.

Since you're going to be doing many replacements (expensive cpu-wise), and you're wanting to simply shorten your coding time, why not also save CPU by wrapping `str_replace()`?

```
function str_wrap($needle,$prefix,$suffix,$haystack) {
    return str_replace($needle, $prefix . $needle . $suffix, $haystack);
}
```

Per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions),
>   you should always use [str_replace()] instead of preg_replace().